# How to create a dynamic chart in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i have to add a chart to display the data ,but nothing appears in the browser.

Here is the code from the controller  which works good:

```
    DAL dal = new DAL();
    public ActionResult Graph2(int Day)
    {
        List<Greenhouse> greenhouse = dal.FindTemperatureByDay(Day);
        return View("DynamicGraph", greenhouse);
    }
```

Here is my model class Greenhouse :

```
public class Greenhouse
{

    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
    public double Humidity { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the view that I tried to put the chart .

```
 @model List<Plotting.Models.Greenhouse> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number','Hour');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
        for (i = 0; i < greenhouse.length; i++) {
            data.addRow(greenhouse[i].DateTime.Hour,greenhouse[i].Temperature);
        }

        var options = {
            'title': 'Daily Report for Humidity',
            'width': 600,
            'height': 500
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `years`? and what is `greenhouse`? where do they come from? You certainly didn't give all the important codes from View.

Comment: Sorry, it should be greenhouse ,but still nothing appears..I edited the code

Comment: greenhouse is send as a  @model List<Plotting.Models.Greenhouse>

Comment: You are using jquery chart please specify which jquery chart you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be recieving the error `Uncaught Error: If argument is given to addRow, it must be an array, or null`.

Your row

`data.addRow(greenhouse[i].DateTime.Hour,greenhouse[i].Temperature);`

should be rephrased to

`data.addRow([greenhouse[i].DateTime.Hour,greenhouse[i].Temperature]);` (the []).

Assuming you are converting your data from the server to javascript correctly.

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/f6zv17yo/)